# How can I summarize the list of values into a number from csv file

Tags: python, loops, sum

im very new to python and was wondering if I can sum the list into a number.

```
import numpy as np
import csv
a = np.unique(data_dict['location'])
for countries in a:
    print (countries)
```

#This currently just lists all the countries with no sum

Comment: What you want to sum? please provide some more details

Comment: What do you mean by sum ? Please clarify your question or give us an expected output / datatype

Comment: share the data_dict pls

Answer (score 0):

If `countries` is a list of integers, you can sum the values with the following command using `Numpy`:

```py
print(np.sum(countries))
```

Comment: Let me know if it doesn't work for you, because you didn't provide details about what your data looks like ...

Comment: hi, im currently receiving "cannot perform reduce with flexible type" 
This is my csv file https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/owid-covid-data.csv